# How to subtract a number in a file name in as.POSIXct in R?

Tags: r

I have several files :

```
dir<- list.files("/data/test", "*.img$", full.names = TRUE)
dir:
/data/test/data.df_df_fg.20141231.jh.ds.0930.edfr.img
/data/test/data.df_df_fg.20141231.jh.ds.1030.edfr.img
/data/test/data.df_df_fg.20141231.jh.ds.1130.edfr.img
```

I want to extract the date from the file names:

```
 dt <-   as.POSIXct(strptime(basename(dir),"data.df_df_fg.%Y%m%d.jh.ds.%H%M.edfr", tz = "GMT"))
dt:

[1] "2014-12-31 09:30:00 GMT"  
[2]"2014-12-31 10:30:00 GMT"                      
[3] "2014-12-31 11:30:00 GMT"
```

What I need is to subtract 1 hour from `dt` so I get:

```
[1] "2014-12-31 08:30:00 GMT"  
[2]"2014-12-31 09:30:00 GMT"                      
[3] "2014-12-31 10:30:00 GMT"
```

and if the hour is `2014-12-31 24:30:00 GMT` , make it `23:30:00 GMT` but also reduce the date to `2014-12-30`.because we are already in the previous day

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
dt-as.difftime(1,units="hours")
```

Comment: It's pretty unusual to have `2430`. That time is usually indicated with `0030`.